# is this mixins code an error of book "The Principles of Object-Oriented JavaScript"

Tags: javascript

in "mixins" chapter, there is an example code

```
function mixin(receiver, supplier) {
    for (var property in supplier) {
        if (supplier.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
            receiver[property] = supplier[property]
        }
    }

    return receiver;
}

function EventTarget(){
}

EventTarget.prototype = {
  add: function(){console.log("add");}
};

function Person(name) {
      this.name = name;
  }
mixin(Person.prototype, new EventTarget());
mixin(Person.prototype, {
      constructor: Person,

      sayName: function() {
          console.log(this.name);
          this.fire({ type: "namesaid", name: name });
      }
  });

  var person = new Person("Nicholas");
```

for my understanding, this is trying to copy properties from EventTarget.prototype into Person.prototype. So the code:

```
mixin(Person.prototype, new EventTarget());
```

should be

```
mixin(Person.prototype, EventTarget.prototype);
```

Am I right of this piece of code?

Comment: It just copies the prototype properties of supplier over to receiver. Supplier can be any kind of object.

Comment: forgot add function EventTarget

Comment: Wow, shadowing native `EventTarget` with a custom one is so misleading.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it's (probably) an error.

The (custom) `EventTarget` constructor is defined as

```js
function EventTarget(){
  // No property assigned to `this`
}
EventTarget.prototype = {
  add: function(){console.log("add");}
};
```

Therefore, an `EventTarget` instance will inherit `add` method from `EventTarget.prototype`, but won't have any own property.

However, the function `mixin` only assigns own properties:

```js
function mixin(receiver, supplier) {
  for (var property in supplier)
    if (supplier.hasOwnProperty(property)) // <--
      receiver[property] = supplier[property]
  return receiver;
}
```

Therefore, the following code does nothing

```js
mixin(Person.prototype, new EventTarget());
```

Comment: Thanks, I agree. I try to find errata online, but get nothing, maybe because the book is relative new.

Answer (score 0):

According to the author Nicholas Zakas, yes it is indeed an error and should instead be:

```
mixin(Person.prototype, EventTarget.prototype);
```

He says this on this [Google Groups thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/zakasbooks/SI_cMctqzAw).